# Java - copy static arrayList from one class to a HashMap in another class

Tags: java, collections

This problem is really really simple, but I have no idea why the suggested solution to a similar question in stackoverflow  doesn't work in my code.

I have a static meleeWeaponList list in MeleeWeapon class, and I want to copy the content of the list to a HashMap (keys) in another class (Blacksmith). The problem is probably in the last three lines in Blacksmith class. What should I fix ? Any suggestion regarding how to deal with the data is more than welcome

```
public class  MeleeWeapon extends Weapon {

boolean throwable;

MeleeWeapon(String name,boolean oneHaned, String reqTraining, int n, int dice, int attackBonus, int damageBonus,double weight, long cost, boolean throwable) {
    super(name, weight, cost, oneHaned, reqTraining, n, dice, attackBonus, damageBonus);
    this.throwable = throwable;
}

static List<MeleeWeapon> meleeWeaponList = new ArrayList<MeleeWeapon>();

static
{
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Long Sword",true, "Martial", 1, 8, 0, 0,8, 10, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Short Sword",true, "Martial", 1, 6, 0, 0,5, 5, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Dagger",true, "Basic", 1, 4, 0, 0,2, 3, true));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Quarter-staff",false, "Basic", 1, 4, 0, 0,3, 2, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Shield",false, "Martial", 1, 4, 0, 0,8, 8, false));

}


public void attack(Character attacker, Character defender){

    int attackRoll = DiceRoller.roll(20) + attacker.getBaseAttackBonus() + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getStrength()) + getAttackBonus() ;
    System.out.println(attacker.getName() + " attack Roll: " + attackRoll + "AC: " + defender.getArmorClass());

    if (attackRoll >= defender.getArmorClass()){
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " had " + defender.getCurrentHp());
        int damage = DiceRoller.roll(getN(), getDice()) + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getStrength()) + getDamageBonus() ;
        System.out.println("Damage : " + damage);
        defender.setCurrentHp(attacker.getCurrentHp() - damage);
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " has " + defender.getCurrentHp());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missed Attack");
    }

}

public static  MeleeWeapon getItem(String itemName) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<MeleeWeapon> iter = meleeWeaponList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            MeleeWeapon item = iter.next();
            if (itemName.equals(item.getName())) {
                return item;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(itemName + " haven't been found");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}


}



public class Blacksmith {

private Map<MeleeWeapon,Integer> meleeMap;
private Map<RangedWeapon,Integer> rangedMap;
private Map<Armor,Integer> armorMap;

Blacksmith(){

    meleeMap = new HashMap<MeleeWeapon, Integer>();
    rangedMap = new HashMap<RangedWeapon, Integer>();
    armorMap = new HashMap<Armor, Integer>();
}

List<MeleeWeapon> meleeList = MeleeWeapon.meleeWeaponList;

for (MeleeWeapon weapon : meleeList) {
    meleeMap.put(weapon, 5);
}



}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. You can't have arbitrary code inside a class. It must be in a method, constructor, or [static] initializer block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put these below statements in a method or constructor or some static block as per your need and you will be good.

```
List<MeleeWeapon> meleeList = MeleeWeapon.meleeWeaponList;

for (MeleeWeapon weapon : meleeList) {
    meleeMap.put(weapon, 5);
}
```

Comment: I put those lines in the constructor and it works. Thanks!! I still think like I'm using  matlab  :)

Comment: @Niminim If it solved your problem you should accept the answer by clicking on the tick

Comment: I tried a few times, but it says that I need to wait 6 more minutes